# using chmod intalling hadoop

Tags: hadoop, fedora, hive

i am following [this blog post](http://krishnasblog.com/2012/05/17/datawarehouse-implementation-using-hadoophbasehivespringbatch-part-2/) which shows how to install hadoop on ubuntu i am trying it on fedora 15

i am having problem at the following line

```
sudo chown <login user>:<machine name>/app/hadoop/tmp
```

my login name is john and the machine name is localhost.localdomain i have inalled fedora on vm ware the command is giving me the following error

> chown: missing operand after `john:localhost.localdomain/app/hadoop/tmp'

please help me in the find out the problem

Comment: i have tried the command without `sudo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo chown john:localhost.localdomain /app/hadoop/tmp
```

Comment: that gives an error `chown: invalid group: `john:localhost.localdomain'`

Comment: My bad - in chown, the operand following the colon denotes the group. Have you created a hadoop group for your system? Is 'john' a member of that group? If so, then you can use chown john:hadoop /app/hadoop/tmp - this assumes the hadoop group is named 'hadoop'

Comment: no i havent can you please take some time and write down the steps to do so i am not that well versed in linux OS...tnx

Comment: Here's a tutorial I used (and found very helpful) when I was starting out - http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/ - in particular, check out the section "Adding a dedicated Hadoop system user"

Answer (score 1):

You could create a group called hadoop and user called hadoop in that group as shown below:

$sudo addgroup hadoop

$sudo adduser --ingroup hadoop hadoop

$sudo chown -R hadoop:hadoop /app/hadoop/tmp

Here is a tutorial for this[Tutorial to setup hadoop cluster](http://students.cis.uab.edu/animeshj/hadoop/setuphadoopcluster.html)

Comment: thn for your time, i am using fedora where you can use `groupadd <group name>` to create a new group